# Removing resources from url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a few nested resources (namespaces, pages and comments), and url looks like this:
`http://example.com/namespaces/objects/pages/super-page` — it's too long.

What is the best way to remove resources names from routes? I want to get something similar to this:
`http://example.com/objects/super-page/`

Update: there are only `show` action in the namespaces controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the path attribute on the reources

```
 resources :pages, :path => '' do
```

I found this article very helpful in customizing my url's http://jasoncodes.com/posts/rails-3-nested-resource-slugs

There is also a great gem for getting rid of the id's and customizing the slug, friendly_id's, http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid

Answer (score 1):

you can use `shallow` parameter in routing
e.g.:

```
resources :namespaces, :shallow => true do
  resources :objects do
    resources :pages
  end
end
```

and then you can use routes like

```
page_path(1) #=> '/pages/1'
object_page_path(1,1) #=> '/object/1/pages/1'
namespace_page_path(1, 1) #=> '/namespace/1/pages/1'
```